# ruby extract data from nested array

Tags: ruby, loops, parsing

How I can access to a depth key value from a nested hash?

I want to extract values inside of _Data, I want to extract the field and size inside data[], to be printed like fieldvalue_sizevalue

```
elemento3_3
```

I have this code but only get the all the data keys and values and i had some troubles making this iteration, I am new at ruby

```
_Data[0][:checks].each do |intera|

puts "#{itera[:data]}

end
```

this is the nested array

```
   _Data =[
    {
      
           
                "agent": "",
                "bottom_comments": [],
                "checks": [
                    {
                        "title": "new",
                        "data": [{

                            "field": "elemento1",
                            "value": "0",
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "new",
                        "data": [{
                            
                            "field": "elemento2",
                            "value": "0",
                            "size":"4",
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "new",
                        "data": [{
                            
                            "field": "elemento3",
                            "value": "0",
                            "size":"3",
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "new",
                        "data": [{
                            
                            "field": "elemento4",
                            "value": "0",
                            "size":"17",
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "new",
                        "data": [{
                            
                            "field": "elemento5",
                            "value": "0",
                            "size":"12",
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "new",
                        "data": [{
                            
                            "field": "elemento6",
                            "value": "0",
                            "size":"19",
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "new",
                        "data": [{
                            
                            "field": "elemento7",
                            "value": "0",
                            "size":"9",
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "new",
                        "data": [{
                            
                            "field": "elemento8",
                            "value": "0",
                            "size":"10",
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "new",
                        "data": [{
                            
                            "field": "elemento11",
                            "value": "0",
                            "size":"14",
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "new",
                        "data": [{
                            
                            "field": "elemento19",
                            "value": "0",
                            "size":"14",
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "condiciones",
                        "elementos": [
                            {
                                
                                "table": [
                                    {
                                        "title": "",
                                        "name": "radio",
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "title": "",
                                        "name": "xenon",
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "title": "",
                                        "name": "aluminio",
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "title": "",
                                        "name": "boro",
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "title": "",
                                        "name": "oro",
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "title": "",
                                        "name": "bromo",
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "title": "",
                                        "name": "oxigeno",
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }

                ]
            
          }
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```rb
_Data[0][:checks].each do |intera|

  intera[:data].each do |data|
    puts "#{data[:filed]}_#{data[:value]}"
  end

end
```

Hope this may help you.

Comment: It gets me the error undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) in the second each, I am really stuck, it supossed to do the iteration inside but none of that works

Comment: @Pedro Sorry, the answer code presume `_Data` structure ,  so it is a way you could iterate `_Data`

Comment: the _Data structure remains, why is te second each not iterating inside of the :data?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one line code to print the values if they exist. Let me know if any further details on any of the methods used will be helpful.

`_Data[0][:checks].pluck(:data).flatten.compact.each{|i| puts "#{i[:field]}_#{i[:size]}" if i[:field] && i[:size]}`

Comment: it gives me the error `<main>': undefined method `pluck' for #<Array:0x0000000004fa5a60> (NoMethodError)       I'm not using Rails, it's just Ruby

Comment: In plain ruby, pluck method can be replaced with collect as below:


`_Data[0][:checks].collect{|x| x[:data]}.flatten.compact.each{|i| puts "#{i[:field]}_#{i[:size]}" if i[:field] && i[:size]}`

Let me know if this works and will update the answer.